Signal and systems, how to find out if T is linear here, given the limited information?
I have the following system which we know is TI (Time Invariant) and we're asked to show if it's linear or not, with only the knowledge of the given values below.

At first, I thought I should have at least a single consistent input; for example having (in the 3 examples) the value at n=1 to plug those back into the expression for linearity, and play with it until I figured something up. This didn't work for me and I tried to use the info that it's a TI system, but that lead me nowhere as well. It's my first time seeing such a question, any help will be appreciated.

Add a scaled x2 to x1 to get a unit impulse. What is the response to that if the system were linear? Now y3 is kind of revealing that response in a delayed way, since x3 is a delayed version of a unit impulse. Does this y3 correspond to a delayed (x1+ k.x2)?

@a360pilot sorry I don't understand your answer

It is a comment, not an answer. The answer is: No, it is not linear :) You can prove this by taking a linear combination of inputs and showing that the output is not a linear combination of outputs. You have three test cases so you should be able to.

@a360pilot I'm sorry but I still don't understand how you got to the answer and your reasoning

We will use the knowledge of Time Invariance, specifically the property of additivity, to solve this problem by contradiction. Let us assume that the system was linear. In that case, we can say that the response to \$x_1[n] - x_2[n] = \delta[n]\$ is equal to \$y_1[n] - y_2[n]\$ which can be expressed as \$2\delta[n-1] +2\delta[n-2] - 4\delta[n-3]\$. Here is where we use the time invariance. Since \$x_3[n] = (x_1[m] - x_2[m])\vert_{m = n-4}\$ (a unit impulse delayed by 4 samples), \$y_3[n] = (y_1[m] - y_2[m])\vert_{m = n-4}\$ must hold by definition. However, it is readily visible that \$y_3[n]\$ does not satisfy such an equality. Hence, proved by contradiction is the fact that the given system is not linear.\$\blacksquare\$

thanks! This has clarified it for me.
